# Change color and size portion of NSString with NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

Browsed through a few `NSAttributedString` examples but can't seem to get this working. I am trying to change the **size** and **color** of part of a `NSMutableAttributedString`.

I've tried a few variations of this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *hintText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is red and huge and this is not"];

//Black and large
[hintText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:20.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]} range:NSMakeRange(0, 11)];

//Rest of text -- just futura
[hintText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:16.0f]} range:NSMakeRange(12, ((hintText.length -1) - 12))];
```

This just changes the size of the text, not the color. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I use this like so: `myUILabel.attributedText = hintText`;

Comment: Where do you use this attributed string?

Comment: The color you're passing in for the NSForegroundColorAttributeName is black, not red. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo on the red/black

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I'm trying to do something like this, I find it to be easier to build individual pieces (each of which is an `NSAttributedString`) and then "glue" them together with something like the following:

```
NSAttributedString *string1 = // Get the red and large string here
NSAttributedString *string2 = // Get the just futura string here

NSMutableAttributedString *hintText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[hintText appendAttributedString:string1];
[hintText appendAttributedString:string2];
```

I find this makes it much easier to follow the logical flow and I've never found this way to have performance limitations that needed optimization.

---

***Update:***

FWIW, I got the following code to work as I believe the OP desires:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSMutableAttributedString *hintText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is red and huge and this is not"];

    //Red and large
    [hintText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:20.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]} range:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];

    //Rest of text -- just futura
    [hintText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:16.0f]} range:NSMakeRange(20, hintText.length - 20)];

    [self.button setAttributedTitle:hintText forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Note that he was specifying `[UIColor blackColor]` and I updated that to `[UIColor redColor]`. Also, I updated the range calculations to include all of the characters in "This is red and huge".

Comment: The OP is using two different ranges in their code. The 2nd is not overwriting the 1st.

Comment: Fair enough. Edited to remove that bit.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the top approach and that works.

Comment: Yeah, I really find it to be more helpful, especially when reviewing/refactoring the code a month (or more) later! Since you approved it, will you up vote it?